# How to clearly identify voice codec used in a VOIP application?

Tags: android, voip, codec

I was going through some sample VOIP SDK for Android. The SDK providers say that they are using the G729 voice codec in the SDK. But those codecs are hidden. Is there any way to clearly identify the voice codec used in the application?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way I know if you have access to the raw audio data only. However, if you can somehow access the signaling data (e.g SIP), you can look at the selected SDP payload. If it is 18 then the call is encoded in G.729.
Hope that helps...